# Jabba the Hutt's Sail Barge: Day the Earth Stood Still name connection?

Tags: star-wars

I've heard that there were a couple characters on Jabba the Hutt's sail barge in *Return of the Jedi* that had names that were inspired by *The Day The Earth Stood Still*.  What were their names, what was the connection, and why?

Comment: Not familiar, but the names would be any of these: Gort, Klatu, Barata, or Nicto.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably heard about [Jabba's Skiff Guards](http://www.rebelscum.com/POTF2jabbasskiffguards.asp); Klaatu, Barada and Nikto.

This is a clear reference to the phrase used in The Day the Earth Stood Still; "*[Klaatu_barada_nikto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaatu_barada_nikto)*"

[image: Toy box branded "Star Wars: The Power of the Force" with a picture of Darth Vader. It is labelled "Jabba's Skiff Guards: Klaatu, Barada, Nikto".]